# If the line $y = mx$ is incident to the point $P(\theta)$ and $\frac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \pi$, find $\sin \theta$ and $\tan \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

I need help with this problem.

> If the line $y = mx$ is incident to the point $P(\theta)$ and $\frac{π}{2}
> < θ < π$, find $\sin \theta$ and $\tan \theta$.

So the angle $θ$ is in the second quadrant. The line $y=mx$ is incident to the point P(θ), so I understand that that the line passes through that point and passes through the origin. So, I was thinking that since $m$ is the slope, the adjacent, opposite, and the hypotenuse of the triangle formed by the reference angle $\alpha$ is $x_2-x_1$, $y_2-y_1$, and $mx$, respectively.

I made a sketch.
[image]

$\sin\theta=\sin\alpha=\frac{y_2-y_1}{mx}$

$\tan\theta=-\tan\alpha=-\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$

I did that but I'm not sure about that and then tangent is not in terms if $m$. If I solve the slope formula for $y_2-y_1$ I get $m(x_2-x_1)$. So then

$\tan\theta=-\tan\alpha=-\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=-\frac{m(x_2-x_1)}{x_2-x_1}=-m$ ????

Please help!!!!

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Your line $y = mx$ is incident with the point $P(\theta)$ where $\theta$ lies in the second quadrant. This means that your line has a negative slope. You can immediately come to the conclusion that this is because of negative x coordinate and positive y coordinate. Use this to calculate $\tan(\theta) = m$ which will be negative and $\sin(\theta) = \frac{m}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$ which will be positive. Hope this helps...

Comment: ok ok!! that makes sense to me. I understand that because we are in the second quadrant the slope of the line is negative. Being said that wouldn't the sine be negative? If $m$ is negative so does the tangent because of the angle in the second quadrant. Then, sine wouldn't be the opposite of that you wrote? doesn't have to have a negative so when multiplying with whatever negative number $m$ is, then it converts to positive because sine is positive in second quadrant.

Comment: No it wont be negative. You see how do you get $m = \tan \theta$. When you calculate $\sin \theta$ you will see that its $\frac{Perpendicular}{Hypotenuse}$. Now from the diagram, Perpendicular is the y coordinate (Positive) and the Hypotenuse is the distance from origin to the point (Again Positive). Only the Base is negative because of negative x coordinate. So $\cos \theta$ will be negative and $\sin \theta$ will be positive. Hope this helps...